# Spotting a mistake in proving if $U_1 + W = U_2 +W$ then $U_1 = U_2$, where $W, U_1, U_2$ are subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I'm working through Axler's [Linear Algebra Done Right](https://linear.axler.net/), and despite being able to find a counter example, I cannot understand *why* my proof is incorrect for the following problem.

**Claim** Let $U_1$, $U_2$, $W$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $U_1 + W = U_2 + W$. Then $U_1$ = $U_2$.

Now, I can find a counterexample easily enough by considering:

\begin{align}
U_1 &= \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{F}^2 \mid a,b \in \mathbb{F}\} \\
U_2 &= \{(a,0) \in \mathbb{F}^2 \mid a \in \mathbb{F} \} \\
W &= \{(0,b) \in \mathbb{F}^2 \mid b \in \mathbb{F} \}
\end{align}

Since I can find a counterexample, the **claim** is clearly not true. However, if I *were* to try and prove the claim, I do *not* understand why the following proof is invalid. I'm very sure it has to do with some conceptual misunderstanding of the material up until this point, but I cannot point to the explicit error in the proof.

**Proof:** Consider $u_1 \in U_1$, $u_2 \in U_2$, and $w \in W$ such that $U_1 + W = U_2 + W$. So, we have $u_1 + w = u_2 + w$, by the definition of the sum of subspaces. Since $U_1 + W$ and $U_2 + W$ contain additive inverses, it is the case that $u_1 + w + (-w) = u_2 + w + (-w) \implies u_1 = u_2$.

$\therefore U_1 = U_2 \quad \blacksquare$

If someone could help point out the conceptual error in the above proof, I woudl very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is you're using the same $w$. It should be $u_1+w_1=u_2+w_2$ for some $w_1,w_2$, not necessarily the same. Therefore, you cannot conclude $u_1=u_2$.

Comment: You can try apply your proof on your counter example to see where it fails, e.g. is $u_1+w$ really equal to $u_2+w$.

Comment: doh! Of course. Thanks 0.o!